# cannot mock CDatabase Open/OpenEx using google mock c++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mfc, googlemock

I am trying to mock Cdatabase method "Open". bellow are the files where I do mock class configurations.

afxdb.h

```
...
    virtual BOOL Open(LPCTSTR lpszDSN, BOOL bExclusive = FALSE,
            BOOL bReadonly = FALSE, LPCTSTR lpszConnect = _T("ODBC;"),
            BOOL bUseCursorLib = TRUE);
...
```

mock_myCDatabase.h

```
...<linkers>

class mock_my_CDatabase :public CDatabase
{
public:
    mock_my_CDatabase()
    {}
    ~mock_my_CDatabase()
    {}
    MOCK_METHOD5(Open, BOOL(LPCTSTR lpszDSN, BOOL bExclusive,BOOL bReadonly, LPCTSTR lpszConnect,BOOL bUseCursorLib));
};
```

DemoClassB.cpp

```
    ...<linkers>
  ...
    CDemoClassB::CDemoClassB(CDatabase  &p_db)
    {
        m_db = &p_db;
    }
  ...
  ...
    BOOL CDemoClassB::fun2()
    {
        m_db->Open((LPCTSTR)NULL, FALSE, FALSE, (LPCTSTR)"ODBC;DRIVER={MICROSOFT ACCESS DRIVER (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ=C:\\Karthik\\GMockDemo\\GMockDemo\\RepolyticsDB.accdb", CDatabase::noOdbcDialog);
            return TRUE;
    }
```

GMockDemo.cpp

```
// GMockDemo.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

...<linkers>

using namespace testing;
using ::testing::Return;


TEST(mock, mockCDatabase)
{
    mock_my_CDatabase mockDb;

    EXPECT_CALL(mockDb, Open((LPCTSTR)"ODBC;DRIVER={MICROSOFT ACCESS DRIVER (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ=C:\\Karthik\\GMockDemo\\GMockDemo\\RepolyticsDB.accdb", CDatabase::noOdbcDialog)).Times(8).WillRepeatedly(Return(TRUE));
    CDemoClassB m_Bt(mockDb);
    ASSERT_EQ(m_Bt.fun2(), TRUE);
}
...
...
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
    RUN_ALL_TESTS();
    std::getchar(); // keep console window open until Return keystroke
    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to mock the CDatabase method: Open . When I run the code I get

**Expected: to be called once
   Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active**

Can anyone please help me in mocking a CDatabase method

Comment: I am not able to find out where i am going wrong. Sorry for the long code. I am new to C++ and google mock. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting warning messages for `uninteresting function calls` on `mock_my_CDatabase::Open`. Check the test ouput.

Try using a [string matcher](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CheatSheet#String_Matchers) for mocked function parameters. You are trying to match the first parameter against a pointer to a literal, which will never match.

Comment: I got the issue solved. your second point was the main reason for the issue I am facing.

I have used "testing::_"

EXPECT_CALL(mock_Db, OpenEx(_, CDatabase::noOdbcDialog)).Times(1).WillOnce(Return(TRUE));

its working thanks.

Comment: @mwKART: Glad to help. Please, edit your question and amend the `Open/OpenEx` error. This is not a forum, you can actually edit questions (and answers) after publishing.